# MySQL trigger after bulk insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I bulk insert a variable amount of rows in a MySQL table:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (0,0), (0,1), ..., (0,N)
```

The first column is always the same, the second column changes in every entry. Now I want to implement a MySQL trigger that uses `col1` to update another table. E.g.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER updateOtherTable AFTER INSERT ON table
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    CALL someProcedure(NEW.col1);
  END;
//
```

However, that would execute `someProcedure()` `N` times which is not necessary since `col1` is always the same for each `INSERT`.

**Is it possible to call this trigger only once and if so, how?**

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can prevent the execution of the trigger for each row.

One option is to use a [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) (be careful with User-Defined Variables) that controls whether to make the call to the stored procedure.

Something like:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `updateOtherTable` AFTER INSERT ON `table`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF @`callSomeProcedure` THEN
    SET @`callSomeProcedure` := NULL;
    CALL `someProcedure`(NEW.`col1`);
  END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23d0b/1)</kbd>